# Javascript won't execute after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

My website contains links and when I click on a click, the target HTML content is loaded into a "div" using JQuery, no problem so far.

My problem is when my search page below is loaded for the third time, the script will not execute:

```
<h1><span>Search</span></h1>
<p class="bigtext">Entity</p>
<input type="text" id="searchfield">
<p class="more">
    <a href="#">Find</a>
</p>
<p></p>
<div id="res"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

Observe that the script works for the two first times, but not for the third time. I have also tried changing the position etc, but no postive results. The problem only occurs for the search page, the HTML content is loaded, I also see the script using Firebug, but it won't execute the alert().

My general load-into-div script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var page = "blog";

    $('a').click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if ( id != null && id !="" )
        {
            page = "index.php/"+id;
            $("#inc").load(page);
        }
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (page=="index.php/toplist")
            $("#inc").load(page);
    }, 6000);
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

// Hirre

Comment: have you try using other browsers? Same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading HTML with `<script>` elements into the page is basically unreliable. jQuery takes a number of steps to try to make it work cross-browser, but in several cases jQuery fails.

So don't rely on it. Keep your script content in the basic script instead, run from callback after loading if necessary.

Comment: Can you give an example please.

Comment: It depends what your code is doing. For the basic case posted above it would be easy to do the alert in a callback: `$("#inc").load(page, function() { alert('hello!'); });`.