# $(document).ready() not executed for ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery

What could be reasons not to execute document.ready within returned partial page?
It works fine 2 times, but on 3rd time nothing happens after update of html:

```
alert(html);
alert($(PopUpItem));
$(PopUpItem).html(html);
alert('in set popup html completed');
```

I have all alerts executed, PopupItem and html has correct values. 
I am using  JQuery to execute server call by $.post.

Also, Can I have error handler to catch if some syntax error happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within your returned AJAX, you shouldn't need a $(document).ready() call. The DOM has already been loaded. Something simple like this should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Do something here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that the `html` string passed to `$(PopUpItem).html()` contains a `<script>` block with a `document.ready(function() { ... });` inside it?

If so the reason the `ready` event handler doesn't fire is that the script doesn't run at all. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176279/javascript-wont-execute-after-load/2176703#2176703) which has the same ‘third-time’ behaviour.

Don't load `<script>` tags into markup. It's not at all reliable cross-browser, jQuery or no jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

document.ready is only executed when the page is originally loaded.

In order to have an error handler, you can use the more $.ajax to do your ajax calls (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

To bind events to any asynchroneously generated elements you should take a look on livequery: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery