# struts2, ajax and injected jquery tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using Struts 2.3 with struts2-jQuery-plugin.

I have to load dynamically with ajax a result from an action.
In the JSP there is some normal html and a jQuery tag

```
<sj:datepicker cssClass="dataScadenzaDiv" id="dataScadenzaDiv"
        name="dataScadenza" maxDate="-1d" label="data scadenza"  theme="xhtml"/>
```

All works OK and the code injected with ajax is:

```
<!-- lotto dpi -->
<tr>
<td class="tdLabel"><label for="lotto" class="label">Lotto:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLotto" size="15" value="" id="lotto"/></td>
</tr>

<!-- tGestDataScadenza -->
<div id="dataScadenzaAjax"></div>
<input type="text" name="dataScadenza" value="" id="dataScadenzaDiv"     class="dataScadenzaDiv" theme="xhtml"/><script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.initDatepicker(false);
});
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var options_dataScadenzaDiv = {};
options_dataScadenzaDiv.showOn = "both";
options_dataScadenzaDiv.buttonImage = "/RadioFrequenza2/struts     /js/calendar.gif";
options_dataScadenzaDiv.maxDate = "-1d";
options_dataScadenzaDiv.jqueryaction = "datepicker";
options_dataScadenzaDiv.id = "dataScadenzaDiv";
options_dataScadenzaDiv.name = "dataScadenza"; jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#dataScadenzaDiv'),options_dataScadenzaDiv    );

});
</script>
```

but now `<input type="text" name="dataScadenza">` is rendered as a normal text
and dot as a datepicker.
I think that the injected javascript is not executed...

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have inserted the <sj:head /> tag in your head section? Is there any log messages in your javascript console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that struts2-jQuery-plugin is generating a script that will run after the DOM is ready: `jQuery(document).ready(function () { ...`

After the page is rendered, the ready event is fired. But after an AJAX call, it is not.

Then you have two solutions:

1. avoid using struts2-jquery-plugin for the JSP snippet that is returned by AJAX; use instead plain jQuery and avoid using `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` 
   <sub>(but I guess it won't be completely reliable);</sub>
2. use a trick to override the default jQuery ready event, [as described in this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125920/1654265), so that the ready function will become triggerable. 
   Then trigger it as last row of your JSP snippet returned by AJAX

   ```
   <sj:datepicker cssClass="dataScadenzaDiv" id="dataScadenzaDiv"
                  name="dataScadenza"        maxDate="-1d" 
                  label="data scadenza"      theme="xhtml"/>
   <script>
        $.triggerReady();
   </script>
   ```

I've made a fiddle showing the trick, and tested it in jQuery 1.10.1:

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/utu7M/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<input type = "button" 
      value = "trigger ready event" 
    onclick = "$.triggerReady();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Overrides jQuery-ready and makes it triggerable with $.triggerReady
// This script needs to be included before other scripts using the jQuery-ready.
// Tested with jQuery 1.10.1
(function(){
var readyList = [];

// Store a reference to the original ready method.
var originalReadyMethod = jQuery.fn.ready;

// Override jQuery.fn.ready
jQuery.fn.ready = function(){
if(arguments.length && arguments.length > 0 && typeof arguments[0] === 'function') {
  readyList.push(arguments[0]);
}

// Execute the original method.
originalReadyMethod.apply( this, arguments );
};

// Used to trigger all ready events
$.triggerReady = function() {
  $(readyList).each(function(){this();});
};
})();


/* This part is for demo only and should be removed */
$( document ).ready(function(){
    alert('document.ready is fired!');
});
```

Remember that also the other handlers originally run in ready event will be triggered again, so use this with caution.