# struts 2 jquery inner html

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a form in a struts 2 webapp. I have the jquery plugin plugin working nicely. However on some of my pages I am reloading div's depending on user interaction and am using the following javascript to submit actions and reload divs on the page :

```
function doWhatever()
{    

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","MyAction.action?id="+1);
xmlhttp.send();    
}
```

This all works fine, except when I reload the div with the result of the action, none of the  jquery tags render correctly on the new page within the div. The regular struts s: tags do render correctly on the new page within the div On the new inner page I have included the same tags as on the main page :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjq" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

 <html>
<head>
<sj:head />
</head>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Struts 2 version 2.3.16.3
struts 2 jquery plugin version : 3.7.1

Spunog

Comment: First of all: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. If you already use `<sj:head/>` in main page then don't include it in the loaded jsp.

Comment: Learn struts2-jquery plugin and write tags if you can't write javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Struts2-jquery-plugin generates scripts running on the `document.ready()` handler.

They works fine at page loading, but they aren't fired in case of a JSP snippet returned through an AJAX call.

Here is a [working and tested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330648/1654265) to this problem.

For general topics about Struts2 and AJAX, you may want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762261/1654265) too.

Comment: I'm finding that a bit hard to follow as I only use jquery through the  struts tags. Could you maybe spell out what I need to do please? Do I just put <script>
     $.triggerReady();
</script> in my inner page ?

Comment: You need to 1) Enhance your up-voting rate on StackOverflow, it's the free way you can reward people the effort they put in helping others; then 2) REDEFINE the document.ready handler, as described in that answer, and 3) APPEND a <script> $.triggerReady(); </script> as LAST LINE of each JSP snippet returned through AJAX in your application. All the work is already done, there is also a running example... just copy paste, and read each line of the answer.