# How to run javascript code included in a page loaded with jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I'm using `jquery.load()` to dynamically load sections of a page.  But I'd like the included sections to both include HTML and be able to execute script.  But a simple

```
<script>
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

doesn't run when I AJAX it in.  Is there another way to dynamically load content such that the scripts will run, or a way to manually run scripts in the included content?  In this case I'm relying on the way `jquery.load` only includes a specific selector from the loaded page.

FWIW I'm using Jquery 1.4.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235967/calling-a-jquery-function-inside-html-return-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript won't execute after load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176279/javascript-wont-execute-after-load)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the script in the loaded page to:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

This should make it run when it's loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me.  Nor is $(document).ready(function(){...});